# Typescript - Unable to access Express Response object

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am unable to use the Response object methods in my ts method and when I log it, it is an empty object. Not sure why it is not getting the response from the import

```
import { Response } from 'express';
async sendRes(res:Response) {
 res.status(200).send();
}
```

I get an error that says `TypeError: res.status is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

First param is for **request** & second for **response** and third for **next** (middleware)

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
async sendRes(req:Request,res:Response) {
 res.status(200).send();
}
```

Comment: why would adding request supposed to work?

Comment: first param is reserved for request second for response and third for next (middleware)